# Scaling Custom Views on orientation change in android

Tags: android, view, android-orientation

I  have a very simple custom view which just draws an oval.

In portrait mode i have this image:
[image: Portrait mode]

In landscape mode i have this image:

[image: Landscape mode]

From these its quite clear that the oval doesn't fit correctly in landscape mode and I would like to scale it down using a ratio of screen size so it appears like that in portrait mode.

Is it possible to do this without xml?

Comment: Of course? It would be more useful to know how you are rendering that oval. However, you might want to _always_ size the oval according to the screen size, not only when the orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onMeasure in your view and apply its new size: 
[onMeasure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29)